# Why is an Aircraft Runway NOT like a Teaspoon?

Tags: aerodynamics, aircraft, propulsion

If the aircraft runway were like a teaspoon (by this I mean, flat in the beginning, then curving downwards and finally upwards), would it not work in favor of the propulsion of the aircraft? In spite of this, why are the runways flat?

Answer (score 13):

The primary factor that determines the ability of an aircraft to takeoff is [having a speed exceeding that of the liftoff speed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takeoff): that is the minimum (air) speed of the aircraft to generate sufficient lift by its wings to counteract the gravitational pull from the earth.

Large passenger planes at takeoff often change the wing configuration (lowers flaps etc) to reduce the required speed: else you would need airplanes traveling at several hundred km/h before takeoff is possible.

The reason that prior to takeoff aircrafts often lift their noses is *not* to change the direction of travel! Indeed, since the aircraft is still on the ground, it is only traveling horizontally. The lifting of the noses is to increase the angle of attack of the wings relative to the direction of travel, thus further lowering the speed required for takeoff.

A runway designed like a spoon would not significantly affect the aerodynamics, if all else being equal. By having the plane go up an incline you are not increasing its speed nor decreasing the require liftoff speed. Hence it would not significantly improve the takeoff of an aircraft.

In fact, for the purpose of increasing the aircraft speed, it is usually better to have the aircraft going *downhill* instead for take-off: that is how many gliders are launched!

(There are, of course, exceptions. For example if the runway is built somewhere there is always a predominant wind, then pitching the runway to accomodate the wind direction may change the aerodynamics.)

Comment: +1 Good explanation. The object is not to get lofted into the air. The object is to reach a speed and angle of attack at which the wings can carry the weight.

Answer (score 4):

A problem I can see with this layout is that it generates a point (at the last upward curvature) for the plane to lift off. In general planes need different runway lengths depending on weight and type of the plane, as well as on external influences like wind.

I therefore assume(!) that a typical flat layout is suited for a wider range of aircraft, and also safer, as it is more forgiving to errors.

Answer (score 3):

If you are particularly short on space, and you have a consistent type (so speed and weight) of aircraft - you can add a ski-jump to help convert the forward speed into vertical lift.

[image]

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but I'm pretty sure that this image is of an Harrier (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harrier_Jump_Jet), an aircraft that can takeoff vertically...

Comment: @J.C.Leitão: Right. Its weight is supported on its downward-thrusting jets (as you can see from the severely downturned flaps and tail), which is assisted by some upward acceleration from the ramp. [*Check the 2nd sentence here.*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harrier_Jump_Jet#Operation)

Comment: @J.C.Leitão - it can take off vertically but it costs a lot of fuel and limits the payload you can carry and these carriers don't have catapults so the ramp gives you more lift at the relatively low take-off speed.

Comment: @Martin Beckett I'm not invalidating your argument, but this factor is relevant for the discussion, mainly because the lift of this aircraft is completely different from standard.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão in a rolling take-off it still uses mostly aerodynamic lift. There is a report on a US attempt to ski ramp various other jet fighters http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a237265.pdf

Comment: Not "vertical lift" (at least in the case of non "jump" jets); it should be "vertical momentum". In the PDF document @Martin linked to, on p.4: "When the Navy first considered using inclined ramps, the objective was to reduce or eliminate the aircraft sinking below the carrier flight deck ... The aircraft leaves the ramp with a vertical velocity ... The speed, however, is below the minimum level flight speed, so the aircraft is not able to maintain its upward velocity. The vertical velocity decreases as the aircraft accelerates and at some point the degradation is stopped."

Comment: @Willie: My favorite example of this is [*Lukla, Nepal*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenzing-Hillary_Airport). The runway is only 1500', with a 12 degree slope. There's a stone wall at one end and a cliff at the other. So you land up-hill and take off down-hill.

Comment: @Willie: Check [*this view of a short final*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:RK_0602_00811_LuklaAnflug.jpg). It looks like the plane is high but it's not. That's because of the slope of the runway.

Comment: @mike Lukla is really the opposite concept of a carrier ski jump.

Comment: @Jonathan: Right. When I fly, the object is not to achieve upward velocity. The object is to reach sufficient airspeed for the wings to support the weight. Aircraft carriers have a problem that often the aircraft does not reach that speed until after leaving the deck, during which time they sink. The ski jump idea gives them a little more surface clearance.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey The idea of Lukla, or an airstrip with which I have personal experience, [Elk City (S90)](https://skyvector.com/airport/S90/Elk-City-Airport), is that the upslope or downslope uses the force of gravity to speed your deceleration or acceleration as you land or takeoff, respectively. Final approach includes a level segment and the flare is a short climb.

Comment: @Jonathan: Curved runway. I'm impressed.